# Comparing two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I would like the query to give me the resulting ID´s whenever a new/subsequent "Close" ended up being higher than *previous* High (you see the dates incrementally growing towards the bottom).

```
ID | Date        | Open | High | Low  | Close
---------------------------------------------
1  | 01.01.2014  | 20   | 22   | 19  |  21 
2  | 02.01.2014  | 21   | 23   | 20  |  23       (this Close is higher than previous High)
3  | 03.01.2014  | 23   | 26   | 18  |  19
4  | 04.01.2014  | 19   | 24   | 18  |  24
```

For instance, for the above stock prices, the result would return:"2", since the "Close" of  ID_2 was higher than "High of ID_1".

I am fiddling with SELF-JOIN, but can´t get this to work. Would very much appreciate a pointer to the right direction.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please show your "fiddling with SELF-JOIN" attempt.

Comment: You can do it by using cursors in oracle DataBase

Comment: The way I see this, you're not very clear about your requirements (be more specific, e.g., are you only interested in the immediately previous day or any previous day?), and you're not showing any research effort. If you want people to take this question seriously you're going to need to fix both these points.

Comment: it's just annoying how one would start a down vote and everyone else would follow without even commenting what the down vote is all about. Just because you have not contributed to the answer does not mean it does not have value.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Here you go

DDL

```
create table shares
(
  id int,
  date_d date,
  open int,
  high int,
  low int,
  close int
  );


insert into shares (id,  date_d,  open,  high,  low,  close)
values 
(1,'01-JAN-2014',20,22,19,21);

insert into shares (id,  date_d,  open,  high,  low,  close)
values 
(2,'02-JAN-2014',21,23,20,23);
insert into shares (id,  date_d,  open,  high,  low,  close)
values 
(3,'03-JAN-2014',23,26,18,19);
insert into shares (id,  date_d,  open,  high,  low,  close)
values 
(4,'04-JAN-2014',19,24,18,24);
```

your SQL

```
select ID,S.DATE_D,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE FROM SHARES S
WHERE CLOSE > (SELECT HIGH FROM SHARES WHERE DATE_D = S.DATE_D-1)
```

you can even see the previous high in this SQL

```
select ID,S.DATE_D,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE, (SELECT HIGH FROM SHARES WHERE DATE_D = S.DATE_D-1) as prev_high FROM SHARES S
WHERE CLOSE > (SELECT HIGH FROM SHARES WHERE DATE_D = S.DATE_D-1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b08a/12

Comment: Above is the solution with the fiddle link. You can use the first query to return the result and the second query to actually check against the previous high